# How to implement Next-auth callback url 302 page

Tags: authentication, next.js, google-oauth, middleware, next-auth

After using Next=auth's the google provider to authenticate myself, I get the redirect callback url which is `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google?state=....` which shows up on the browser for a split second as a ERR_INVALID_URL page and then redirects me to the homepage of my application. I want the user to have an intermediate page such as a loading screen so that they would not see an invalid page even for split second.